# ld.exe: cannot find -ldwrite and -ldwmapi

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, mingw, codelite

As the title, I have this error while compiling an hello world demo with gtk in codelite...the exactly error is

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -e -f  Makefile
Building project:[ CodeLiteGTK3 - Debug ]----------
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Diana/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/CodeLiteGTK3'
C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/CodeLiteGTK3 @"CodeLiteGTK3.txt" -L.   -L/mingw64/lib -L/mingw64/lib/../lib -L/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lepoxy -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lm -lgdi32 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lm -lpangowin32-1.0 -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfribidi -lthai -ldatrie -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lz -lpixman-1 -lm -pthread -lfontconfig -liconv -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -ldwrite -lgraphite2 -lpng16 -lz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lgdiplus -lole32 -ljpeg -ljasper -lpng16 -lz -ltiff -lzstd -llzma -ljpeg -lz -lgio-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lshlwapi -ldnsapi -liphlpapi -lws2_32 -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -lintl -lz -lgobject-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lffi -lintl -lglib-2.0 -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -pthread -lpcre
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwmapi
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwrite
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Debug/CodeLiteGTK3] Error 1
CodeLiteGTK3.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/CodeLiteGTK3' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Diana/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/CodeLiteGTK3'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

here the code.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I run the codelite wizard to set all compiling and linking tools (mingw. that works, hello world without gtk works), after I Iinstalled (via pacman) gtk and that's all

Comment: I added the code in the post. It's strange another things. if the file is with main.c (c extension) I get this errore. If I use main.cpp (cpp extension) It tell me that gtk.h is not found. I need cpp file. I'm sorry for my english, I hope you understand. Thanks nononck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as g++ option, add `-I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0/`

in Settings -> Build setting -> Compilers

[image]

click Apply Ok  ..I haven't tried for setting clang++ as compiler though

BTW, edit the code with print Hello world at the first place said